# Removing cloud-init from Minimized Server marks important network packages for removal

Tags: server, 22.04, ubuntu-minimal, cloud-init

I have tested removing `cloud-init` using [this guide](https://gist.github.com/zoilomora/f862f76335f5f53644a1b8e55fe98320) on Ubuntu Server 22.04 and Ubuntu Server 22.04 (minimized) installed with the default settings. Uninstalling `cloud-init` from full Ubuntu Server does not mark important packages for removal, but doing it from the minimized version did so. See the screenshot below. If I execute `sudo apt autoremove` after that, and restart the server, the Internet is no longer accessible and all Internet-related commands are not found.

Is that a bug? If not, can I remove cloud-init from the minimized version without destroying network access? I am not using cloud. I just wanted a bare-minimum Ubuntu desktop (I add XFCE to this).

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like a bug -- it looks like expected behavior when you remove a key component. A lot of folks install Ubuntu Server using cloud-init, so it's a convenient top-level package for a lot of dependencies. Go through that list, trace the dependencies and reverse-dependencies of the packages that you want to keep, and apt-mark the top-level packages "manual" so those stacks are ineligble for autoremoval. Many of us have been through the I-want-a-bare-minimum-system phase of life. This is the tedious work you must do for a bare minimum system. It's a good learning experience.

Comment: @user535733 Eh. I decided disabling cloud-init, instead. Cloud-init seems to make booting slow, too.

Comment: @user535733: it's not a key component; it's completely pointless unless you're installing at a cloud/VPS/etc provider, in which case it lets the provider give you a single stock image, with an alternative route to set up things like usernames and passwords. And even that is not necessary if the provider lets you install your own customised image. And it plays badly with unattended security upgrades, as cloud-init updates require user intervention which is never going to happen. For most people, it's useless dead weight which should be pruned.

Comment: Curious. I've historically disabled instead of uninstalled, and I'll stick with that after seeing this. This is definitely a bug if DHCP is disabled, as it looks like it is. My own minimal images uninstall netplan anyway, and  set static addressing. As a data point, `apt purge netplan.io` will also remove cloud-init.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced the same.

On the second try I did it in this order without rebooting between the commands...

apt purge cloud-init

rm -rf /etc/cloud

apt purge unattended-upgrades

rm -rf /var/log/unattended-upgrades

apt autoremove

apt install netplan.io

apt install isc-dhcp-client

Then rebooted and network was still working with the values entered on installation.

And I would say, removing netplan.io with whatever as dependency should clearly be seen as a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Mark packages manual before autoremove:

apt purge cloud-init cloud-guest-utils -y

**apt-mark manual** netplan.io software-properties-common fdisk gdisk isc-dhcp-client tzdata

apt autopurge -y